# mostrar los datos en un formulario antes de que sean actualizados

Tags: java, html, formularios, jsp, update

estoy intentando mostrar los datos del usuario que pretendo actualizar.

En mi estructura introduzco un dni que se extrae al consultar una lista, para luego mostrar los datos del usuario en concreto en otro formulario. Cuando este formulario sea mandado los datos quedarán actualizados definitivamente.

El problema que tengo es que no se como mostrar los datos del usuario que previamente he buscado.
P.E: Busco un usuario called Jhon Doe with DNI 11111111E, in the second form i will have a new form with name and surname  juan nadie, ahora escribo en esos campos del formulario miguel nadie y presiono subbmit.

El problema: no sé como mostrar el nombre antiguo en mi formulario( es decir, no se como mostrar a juan Nadie)

Estoy atascado en esta parte, la actualización es correcta, pero no logro mostrar los campos.

Os adjunto el código

1º-Aquí mi primera página del formulario, de donde saco el DNI previa muestra de un listado.

```
    <%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="Entidades.Usuario"%>
<%@page import="DAO.DAOUsuario"%>
<%@page import="Conexion.DBConnection"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<jsp:useBean id="usuario" class="Entidades.Usuario" />
<jsp:setProperty name="usuario" property="*"/>

<%
String message = "";
List<Usuario> usuarios = null;
DAOUsuario dao = new DAOUsuario();

try {
    //usuarios = dao.selectUsuario("si","nombre");
    usuarios = dao.selectAllUsuarios();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    message = ex.toString();
}
%>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>V2formListarUsuariosAltaNombre</title>
    <link href="../css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>   
    <div class="titulo">
        <h1>BIBLIOTECA - LISTADOS USUARIOS</h1>
        <div id="menu">
            <div id="opciones">
                <h2><a href="../Menu.jsp">Menu inicial</a></h2>
                <h2><a href="V2HojaUsuarios.jsp">Atras</a></h2> 
            </div>
            <form id="formulario" action="V2formModificarUsuario2(en obras).jsp" method="POST">
                <label for="DNI">Intruduzca DNI del usuario</label><br> 
                DNI: <input type="text" name="DNI" required="">
                <input type="submit" value="buscar"> 
            </form>  
            <form>
                <%if (!message.isEmpty()) {%>
                <input name="status_initial" type="text" style="width:400px" value="<%=message%>"/>
                <%} else { %>

                <br/><br/>

                <table border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <th>DNI</th>
                        <th>nombre</th>
                        <th>apellidos</th>
                        <th>de alta</th>

                    </tr>
                    <%for (int i = 0; i < usuarios.size(); i++) {%>
                    <tr>

                        <td><%=usuarios.get(i).getDNI()%></td>
                        <td><%=usuarios.get(i).getNombre()%></td>
                        <td><%=usuarios.get(i).getApellidos()%></td>
                        <td><%=usuarios.get(i).getDeAlta()%></td>

                    </tr>                            
                    <%}%>
                </table>
                <%}%>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

2º-Aquí la segunda hoja del formulario, donde actualizo los datos al completar un formulario que debería tener en sus campos los datos del usuario que he seleccionado (y que es donde está mi pregunta)

```
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="Entidades.Usuario"%>
<%@page import="DAO.DAOUsuario"%>
<%@page import="Conexion.DBConnection"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<jsp:useBean id="usuario" class="Entidades.Usuario"></jsp:useBean> 
<jsp:setProperty name="usuario" property="*"/>

<%
String message = "";


// String nameToChange = "";
String surnameToChange = "";

try {
    if ((usuario.getDNI() != null) && (!usuario.getDNI().isEmpty())) {
        DAOUsuario dao = new DAOUsuario();   

       // nameToChange=dao.selectByDNI(request.getParameter("DNI")).getNombre(); comentado por ahora
        surnameToChange=dao.selectByDNI(request.getParameter("DNI")).getApellidos(); 
        Usuario usuarios = dao.selectByDNI(usuario.getDNI());

        if (usuarios != null) {
            if ((usuario.getNombre() != null) && (!usuario.getNombre().isEmpty())
                    && (usuario.getApellidos() != null) && (!usuario.getApellidos().isEmpty())) {

                dao.update(usuario.getDNI(), usuario.getNombre(), usuario.getApellidos());
                message = "User correctly updated.";
            } else {
                if (request.getParameter("updating") == "1") {
                    message = "Los campos name, surname and deAlta are required .";
                }
            }
        } else {
            message = "user do not exists.";
        }
    } else {
        message = "DNI must not be null.";
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    message = ex.getMessage();
}
%>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSPformModificarUsuario2(en obras)</title>
    <link href="css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>  
    <div class="titulo">
        <h1>BIBLIOTECA - USUARIO</h1>
        <div id="menu">
            <div id="opciones">
                <h2><a href="index.jsp">Inicio</a></h2> 
            </div>
            <form method="POST" action="V2formModificarUsuario2(en obras).jsp">
                <input name="updating" type="hidden" value="1"/>

                <%if (!message.isEmpty()) {%>
                <input name="message" type="text" style="width:400px" value="<%=message%>"/>
                <%} else { %>

                <br/><br/>

                DNI:
                <input name="DNI" type="text" style="width:200px" value="<jsp:getProperty property="DNI" name="usuario"/>" readonly=""/>

                <br/><br/>
                nombre:
                <input name="nombre" type="text" style="width:200px" placeholder="<%=apellidoActualizar%>" value="<jsp:getProperty property="nombre" name="usuario"/>"/>

                <br/><br/>
                apellidos:
                <input name="apellidos" type="text" style="width:200px" value="<jsp:getProperty property="apellidos" name="usuario"/>"/>

                <br/><br/>
                <input type="submit" value="Actualizar"/>

                <%}%>
            </form>
       </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

3º-Y aquí los DAO que he empleado, están correctos.

```
 public Usuario update(String DNI, String nombre, String apellidos) throws Exception {
    if ((DNI == null) || (DNI.isEmpty())) {
        throw new Exception("DNI must not be null");
    }
    if ((nombre == null) || (nombre.isEmpty())) {
        throw new Exception("name must not be null");
    }
    if ((apellidos == null) || (apellidos.isEmpty())) {
        throw new Exception("surname must not be null");
    }

    Usuario usuario = selectByDNI(DNI);
    if (usuario == null) {
        throw new Exception("user do not exist");
    }
    try (Connection connection = DBConnection.get()) {
        if (connection == null) {
            throw new Exception("Connection is null");
        }

        String query = "UPDATE usuario SET nombre=?, apellidos=? WHERE DNI=?";

        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        statement.setString(1, nombre);
        statement.setString(2, apellidos);
        statement.setString(3, DNI);
        statement.execute();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        DBConnection.close();
    }
    usuario = selectByDNI(DNI);
    return usuario;
}

public Usuario selectByDNI(String DNI) throws Exception {
    if ((DNI == null) || (DNI.isEmpty())) {
        return null;
    }
    Usuario usuario = null;
    try (Connection connection = DBConnection.get()) {
        if (connection == null) {
            throw new Exception("Connection is null");
        }
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE DNI = '" + DNI + "'");

        if (rs.next()) {
            usuario = new Usuario(rs.getString("DNI"), rs.getString("nombre"),
                    rs.getString("apellidos"), rs.getString("deAlta"));
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        DBConnection.close();
    }
    return usuario;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

lo he resuelto, hacía falta una hoja más de formulario, en la primera creo el objeto con el DNI buscado, extraigo sus valores y muestro en placeholder el valor y también en el value, conecto este formulario con otro por post y le paso los valores, comprobando si esos valores están o no vacios o son nulos.

Luego doy a varias variables los valores del formulario anterior con getParameters y creo un objeto con un DAOUpdate que tengo preparado y que modifica los usuarios en la bbdd independientemente de su alta o baja,y finalmente se manda mensaje informando.

### formulario 2

```
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="Entidades.Usuario"%>
<%@page import="DAO.DAOUsuario"%>
<%@page import="Conexion.DBConnection"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<jsp:useBean id="usuario" class="Entidades.Usuario"></jsp:useBean> 
<jsp:setProperty name="usuario" property="*"/>

<%
String message = "";
String nombreActualizar = "";
String apellidoActualizar = "";

try {
    if ((usuario.getDNI() != null) && (!usuario.getDNI().isEmpty())) {
        DAOUsuario dao = new DAOUsuario();
        nombreActualizar = dao.selectByDNI(request.getParameter("DNI")).getNombre();
        apellidoActualizar = dao.selectByDNI(request.getParameter("DNI")).getApellidos();
    } else {
        message = "El DNI  de actualización no puede ser nulo.";
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    message = ex.getMessage();
}
%>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSPformModificarUsuario2(en obras)</title>
    <link href="../css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>  
    <div class="titulo">
        <h1>BIBLIOTECA - USUARIO</h1>
        <div id="menu">
            <div id="opciones">
                <h2><a href="../Menu.jsp">Menu inicial</a></h2>
                <h2><a href="V2formModificarUsuario1.jsp">Atras</a></h2> 
            </div>
            <form method="POST" action="V2formModificarUsuario3.jsp">
                <input name="updating" type="hidden" value="1"/>

                <%if (!message.isEmpty()) {%>
                <input name="message" type="text" style="width:400px" value="<%=message%>"/>
                <%} else {%>

                <br/><br/>

                DNI:
                <input name="DNI" type="text" style="width:200px" value="<jsp:getProperty property="DNI" name="usuario"/>" readonly=""/>

                <br/><br/>
                nombre:
                <!-- <input name="nombre" type="text" style="width:200px" value="<<!--jsp:getProperty property="nombre" name="usuario"/>"/>-->
                <input name="nombre" type="text" style="width:400px" placeholder="<%=nombreActualizar%>" value="<%=nombreActualizar%>"/>
                <br/><br/>
                apellidos:
                <!--<input name="apellidos" type="text" style="width:200px" value="<<!--jsp:getProperty property="apellidos" name="usuario"/>"/>-->
                <input name="apellidos" type="text" style="width:400px" placeholder="<%=apellidoActualizar%>" value="<%=apellidoActualizar%>"/>
                <br/><br/>
                <input type="submit" value="Actualizar"/>

                <%}%>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

### formulario 3

```
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="Entidades.Usuario"%>
<%@page import="DAO.DAOUsuario"%>
<%@page import="Conexion.DBConnection"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<jsp:useBean id="usuario" class="Entidades.Usuario"></jsp:useBean> 
<jsp:setProperty name="usuario" property="*"/>

<%
String message = "";
DAOUsuario dao = new DAOUsuario();
String DNIActualizado="";
String nombreActualizado ="";
String apellidoActualizado = "";

if (
        ((request.getParameter("DNI") == null) || (request.getParameter("DNI").isEmpty()))
     || ((request.getParameter("nombre") == null) || (request.getParameter("nombre").isEmpty()))
     || ((request.getParameter("apellidos") == null) ||(request.getParameter("apellidos").isEmpty()))
        ) {
    message = "Ningún campo del formulario debe estar vacio.";
}else{

DNIActualizado=request.getParameter("DNI");
nombreActualizado=request.getParameter("nombre");
apellidoActualizado=request.getParameter("apellidos");

usuario=dao.update(DNIActualizado, nombreActualizado, apellidoActualizado);
message = "usuario con DNI "+request.getParameter("DNI")+" actualizado";
}



%>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSPformModificarUsuario3(en obras)</title>
    <link href="../css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>  
    <div class="titulo">
        <h1>BIBLIOTECA - USUARIO</h1>
        <div id="menu">
            <div id="opciones">
                <h2><a href="../Menu.jsp">Menu inicial</a></h2>
                <h2><a href="V2formModificarUsuario2(en obras)">Atras</a></h2> 
            </div>
            <form method="POST" action="V2formModificarUsuario3(en obras).jsp">
                <input name="updating" type="hidden" value="1"/>

                <%if (!message.isEmpty()) {%>
                <input name="message" type="text" style="width:400px" value="<%=message%>"/>
                <%} else {%>

                <br/><br/>

                DNI:
                <input name="DNI" type="text" style="width:200px" value="<jsp:getProperty property="DNI" name="usuario"/>" readonly=""/>



                <%}%>
            </form>
       </div>
    </div>
</body>
```